# AES ECB cookie bypass

Tags: aes, cookies, ctf

I am currently participating in a CTF Challenge and have reached a stage where I discovered a "log_admin" page. This page generates a cookie that is encrypted using AES 128 ECB. I obtained this information by retrieving the page's source code, which is provided below:

```
<?php

# @TODO: Remove debug stuff for prod
#      : Implement svc and svcparam 
#
session_start();
$DEBUG = 0;

$key =  getenv("AES_KEY");

if(!isset($_COOKIE['admin'])){
    $svc=(isset($_GET['svc'])) ? $_GET['svc'] : "crawl";
    $svcparam=(isset($_GET['svc_param'])) ? $_GET['svc_param'] : "url";
    if(preg_match("/adm=1/i", $svc) || preg_match("/adm=1/i", $svcparam) ) die('Hacking attempt detected');
    $date = date("Ymd");
    $str_cookie = "service=".$svc.";adm=0;service_param=".$svcparam.";date=".$date;
    $cookie = openssl_encrypt($str_cookie, "AES-128-ECB", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
    setcookie('admin', base64_encode($cookie));
    $_COOKIE['admin'] = base64_encode($cookie); 
}

if(strpos(openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($_COOKIE['admin']),"AES-128-ECB",$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA), 'adm=1') !== false){
    $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
    header("Location: admin.php");
}

if(isset($_GET['DEBUG'])){
    $a = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($_COOKIE['admin']), "AES-128-ECB", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
    print $a;
}"
```

I understand that the objective is to create a cookie with the value `adm=1` in it, and since it is encrypted using AES ECB, I need to exploit the diffusion vulnerability to manipulate the cookie.

However, I have been analyzing the cookie pattern for some time now, and I am unable to identify repetitive blocks that would allow me to manipulate the cookie effectively. If anyone has any suggestions or insights, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need repetitive patterns. Since the encryption doesn't involve any integrity protection, you can inject your own plaintext using the URL parameter `svc`, obtain the encrypted cookie and then reassemble or delete blocks of the ciphertext to get the plaintext you want.

Note that `svc` is checked for `adm=1`, so you cannot inject this substring directly. However, if you inject `adm=[SOME PADDING BYTES]1` and then remove the encrypted `[SOME PADDING BYTES]` from the ciphertext, you can get `adm=1` without running into the check. Hint: If `adm=` ends at an AES block boundary, and `1` starts at a block boundary, it's easy get get rid of all data in between by deleting the corresponding block(s).